# how to open a file at a specific line in an existing vim window?

Tags: vim

I can open file at a specific line in mvim (on OSX, gvim on linux etc) with `mvim file_path +file_line`

I can open file in an existing window by `mvim --remote-tab file_path`

but I can't combine the two. when I do `mvim --remote-tab file_path +file_line` I get 2 tabs, one for the file, and another for a new file named +file_line ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `--remote-tab` can only take one +cmd and it must come first:

```
mvim --remote-tab +file_line file_path
```

See `:help --remote`